# Facebook Like Box - is there any way to code the API to feed comments from the page wall?

Tags: facebook, comments, facebook-likebox

Facebook Like Box - is there any way to code the API to feed comments from the page wall? I'd like to feed both posts and comments, in addition to posts from visitors through to the website page calling the plugin. Possible?